# Unrecognized switch for Cygwin mount command

Tags: command-line, mount, cygwin

I'm trying to configure the cygwin to work with TWiki, I have to input this in the Cygwin bash shell:

```
mount -b -s c:/...
```

but it doesn't recognize the `-s`, I already fixed the problem with `-b`, it changed the syntax and now is `mount -o binary` for the `mount -b` part. But now it says unknown option with the `-s` What does the `-s` mean, so I can look it up?

Comment: `mount --help` would be my guess...

Answer (score 1):

cygwin's `mount` does not support the `-s` option, but I doubt you need it.

Here is what it does:

> **-s**
>       Tolerate sloppy mount options rather than failing. This will ignore mount options not supported by a filesystem type. Not all filesystems support this option. This option exists for support of the Linux autofs-based automounter.